# Silverlight permission?? error

Tags: silverlight-4.0

While trying to build one of the targets of my project, I get an error which seems to be a permission issue. And am struggling to resolve this issue. The issue is pasted below. Any suggestion would be of great help. Thanks for your patience and help.

> "R:\Export\Exporting.sln" (default target) (2)
>
> "R:\Export\WebHost\Export.WebHost.csproj" (default target) (70)
>
> "R:\Export\WebHost\SilverlightClient\Export.SilverlightClient.csproj" (default target) (71:2)
>
> (ValidateXaml target)
>
> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(214,9): error : Could not load the assembly file:///R:\Report\Export\SilverlightClient\obj\Debug\Export.SilverlightClient.dll.
>
> This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information. [R:\Export\SilverlightClient\Export.SilverlightClient.csproj]"

Where `R:` is a Clearcase Snapshot view.
The tip ( http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 ) is not helping since that dll is not blocked as assumed.

-Bobs

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by editing two config files.

1. <>:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config
   and
2. <>\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe.config

added the entry  within "runtime".

This msdn link helped me -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252.aspx

-bobs